# processing growing excel file with java spring

Tags: java, excel, spring, apache-poi

I want to process an excel file with java spring. I am using apche poi to process the file. The excel file is auto generated and keeps growing. Example: Excel file has 20 lines on day 1. On day 2 the excel file has 35 lines. The first 20 lines are the same, but there are 15 new lines. It is unknown how many lines are added or when the excel will be uploaded.
The data from the excel is mapped to POJOs and saved to the database.

Is there a fast and reliable way to identify which new lines were added and only proccess those lines?

edit: I realised that this might not be an excel processing problem but (also) a database optimisation problem.

Comment: Can't you keep track of how many lines were in the file in the previous read and then skip that many when reading next time? i.e. - had 100 lines. Next time start reading from 101st

Comment: The question is too broad, I think. What have you already tried? Is there any unique Id in each line, or field that can serve as ID?

Comment: I tried to index the database on the unique combination of columns,
I tried batch inserting to just make one trip to the database and not for every new entry.
The problem with tracking the line number is too risky. I can't be sure that nobody has deleted any lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the newer API of Apache POI, SXSSF, which an API-compatible streaming extension of XSSF to be used when very large spreadsheets have to be produced, and heap space is limited. It consumes less memory. Check this [link](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api).

Comment: this doesn't answer the ops question. If one has problems to store the number of rows of the previous day, one shouldn't start with SXSSF in the first place